# SSIS - best way to integrate business rules?

Tags: design-patterns, metadata, ssis

What is the best way to separate business rules in data transformations from data loading/extracting in SSIS?

Is there a known pattern in SSIS that supports this design? (without external technology, like custom tasks using c#).

From what I've experienced, the 2 are done simultaneously with derived columns, conditional splits and the like.

Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a common pattern for loading a data warehouse...

1. Extract the data from the source system(s).  Whether you stage the raw source data in a separate staging area before the next step depends on several factors that I won't get into here.
2. Transform the data as needed to fit your destination - which is typically a star-schema data model.  This is when the business rules are applied in addition to the normal stuff like surrogate key lookups.
3. Load the data into data mart/warehouse

In this sense, because the application of business rules/logic occurs in the transformation step...it is separate from the Extract/Loading steps.

*Is there something more specific you are trying to accomplish?  (I'm asking because of the "metadata" tag)*

Comment: To be more specific, is there a way to separate point 2 in two parts: business rules and data specific validation (cleansing, formatting, data types, etc)?

Comment: Can you give me a few examples of what you mean by "business rules"?

Comment: a business rule would be to make sure the currency is CAD or USD, contrasted with data validation that makes sure its not CDN or USA currency for example (or any other invalid data). Im looking for a pattern in SSIS to group up all the business rules and group up all the data validation rules.

Comment: grouping tasks can be accomplished in a variety of ways.  you could, for example, encapsulate the logic in separate packages and link them together with Execute Package Tasks in the control flow.  1) Extract the data from source, 2) execute a package that carries out data validation logic, 3) execute a package that carries out business rule logic, 4) load data.